# What should be the testing approach of 100 Television Products?

Tags: manual-testing, interview

This will be a interview question from Amazon.

- What should be the testing approach of 100 Television Products?
- What will be the Scenario & how long it will take to complete this?

Can anybody post answer for this question?

Comment: What are your thoughts up to now?

Comment: I think the question which you have asked can't have a definite answer. It's answer will be more opinion based or you can say more based on individual skill set and his view towards this question.

Answer (score 1):

I ask a question like this to my interviewees. There is no right answer. The question is an exercise in problem solving and how you would tackle it. Like tickets you will be assigned, the requirements are vague and it is up to you to get clarification by asking the right questions.

> What should be the testing approach of 100 Television Products? How long it will take to complete this?

What kind of products? Do the products differ in any way? Is there a test plan already? Historically, how long has this taken in the past? So on and so on...

**My similar interview questions:**

- How much would you charge to wash all the windows in Denver?
- How many ping-pong balls would it take to fill a limo?
- For more, check out the "Google interview questions" on the web

Answer (score 0):

There are details missing from the question so asking clarification questions would be the first step, the next step should be summarizing your assumptions.
Since this is Amazon you should keep in mind while answering some ility words

- Scalability
- Parallelism of the test
- Cross platform (well, this is not a ility word)
- Traceability, debuggability and logging

then think about your test framework and how do you want to show results.

Remember- interview question are not always about right or wrong but about how do you think, or about things that were not explicitly asked.

Comment: What do those "-ility" words mean in the context of television products?

Comment: The same as in the context of any other product, not to mention that today's televisions contains a fair amount of software.

I also guess that the question is for a SOFTWARE testing position. 

Scalability- what if you wnated to test 1,000 televisions ? 1,000,000 ?
Parallelism- an easy way for Scalability
Cross platform- testing NTSC and PAL, SD and HD, 16:9 and 3:4, Android and Windows 10 are all basically the same but slightly different.
Traceability- when you test so many devices you must think of an efficient way of keeping track of things

Answer (score 0):

First, you should gather the end user requirements i.e. about TVs.

Second, the question is incomplete. It just said about "TV". In this case, you need to throw lot of questions about TV before you start creating test scenarios and estimating the time.

1. What type of TV?
2. What is the dimension of the product?
3. What kind of features that TV supports?
4. Is it a Smart TV, Plasma TV, LED, LCD, HD etc?
5. What kind of TV accessories are in-scope?
6. UI aspects
7. Performance aspects
8. Durability aspects
9. Reliability aspects
10. End-user warranty details
11. Security aspects
12. Power supply options
13. etc.,

Then you need to create use cases and get a sign-off from the manufacturer. After sign-off, you can start creating test scenarios and test cases.